# horizontally align elements under <label> tag

Tags: html, css

I'd like to line up the text of a label and a div under that label horizontally, but the div keeps wrapping to the next line.  Here's what I've tried so far.

**HTML**

```
<label>
   <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_23_549" value="2"> 25-50% 
   <div class="actual">=&gt; Actual EF 30%</div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.actual {
    text-wrap:none;
}
.wpProQuiz_questionInput {
    text-wrap:none;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grgjq9uh/11/)

Comment: There is no `text-wrap` property.

Comment: That HTML is invalid.. It's not valid to nest a `div` element in a `label` element..

Comment: @JoshCrozier http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly your html in the site is not the html you share with us. See my comment in my answer. It works perfectly. And my answer was the first of the 6 answers here (now 4 because 2 was removed). Take in your mind when accept answers ;) Maybe the next can be copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to inline-block and it works

https://jsfiddle.net/grgjq9uh/12/

```
.actual {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Your page doesn't have the correct html. You have not the text wrapped in the `<div class="actual">`. Doesn't matter what name do you put to the classname, but you need to wrap the text in an inline-block element to work. Finally you need to have this code: `<label><input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" name="question_23_552" value="3" type="radio"><div class="actual">&lt;25%</div></label>`

Answer (score 1):

`text-wrap` is not a valid CSS property. What you're probably looking for is the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

`div` has `display:block;` by default so it goes to the second line, however, you can use `display:inline-block;` or change your `div` element to a `span` element.

**display:inline-block;**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grgjq9uh/14/)

```css
.actual {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_23_549" value="2">25-50%
  <div class="actual">=&gt; Actual EF 30%</div>
</label>
```

**Span element**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grgjq9uh/16/)

```html
<label>
  <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_23_549" value="2">25-50%
  <span class="actual">=&gt; Actual EF 30%</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` is wrapping to the next line because its default `display` is `block`.

Try changing it to:

```
.actual {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grgjq9uh/15/)